Creating tabs inside TabBar based on FutureBuilder
I'm looking for a way, to create a TabBarView inside a FutureBuilder. I've came to the following solution and everything is working fine:
body: FutureBuilder<List<PrayerTimes>>(
  future: futureAlbum,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Text(snapshot.data![0].date)
        ]
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
)
...

However I have some trouble to create the tabs based on the futureAlbum inside the TabBar. An error The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. appears and I've no clue what I can do (differently):
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      // Doesn't work
      tabs: futureAlbum.map((sub){
        return Tab(icon: Text(sub.date));
      }).toList(),
    )  
)
...

The futureAlbum is a simply async-function, that fetches and returns JSON-Data.

As futureAlbum is a Future, it's normal that it does not have a map method.

So there is no opportunity to do that with FutureBuilder?

You can try following stuff:
Wrap your AppBar with FutureBuilder and return null (or maybe add TabBar with unclickable tabs) in bottom parameter of your AppBar if there is no data in your snapsnot. However, this might not be really good solution for your layout because TabBar will suddenly appear one moment so I would recommend you to try somehow fetch data while user is on another page and pass it to your page you have issue with

Push the FutureBuilder above that scaffold:
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: ...,
      builder:{
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return Scaffold(
      // Build all , data has been reached
      );
    }
  } 
  );

